# Nodes order in xml created from dataset

Tags: xsd, dataset

I'am filling tables in .net DataSet with data.
There is a nested relation between the tables, so the exported XML (by using GetXml() method) is nested (the child rows are becoming child nodes).

I 'am sending this XML to a conversion module that converts the XML from the DataSet schema (I' am using the dataset XSD file) to other schema by XSLT map.

The problem is that in the XML that I' am receiving from the DataSet (by using GetXml method) the child nodes are not in the correct order (different from the order they are in the schema). From this reason the schema validation in the conversion module is failing!

I've found this W# documentation:
[All or Sequence](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp)

I've tried to act according to this, but it seems like the value "all" can't "live" with the relations between the tables in the DataSet and I'am getting many weird error messages.

Is there a better way to control the child nodes order or to make the schema to succeed in the validation process even if the order is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use explicit select statements in your SQL

```
 SELECT Column1, Column2 From ...
```

If this isn't possible, you will need to make your XSD match your physical table specifications.